# If I unpublish my app on Google Play, will I still have to update my app to support the new Android Version?

Tags: android, google-play

I have a deadline by November to update my app to target the new Android system.
But I can't upgrade now, because of what I'm through, like studying, etc.

If I don't publish an update by November, the app will be gone forever and I'll have to republish it. (At least that's what I understood)

Anyways, the real question is:- If I unpublish my app on Google Play, will I still have to update my app to support the new Android Version? Or will Google just ignore me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Unpublish your app, Google will no longer check your app for most of violation (some violation like copyright issues will still be a problem). So you do not have to update your app until you republish it again in future.

Answer (score 1):

If you unpublish you will be delisted so "no". But to restore your entry you will have to publish the update. Still, your current users will not be affected